# Recyclerview item onClick to set the image clicked in a ImagemView container

Tags: android-recyclerview, onclick, setimagebitmap

The solution to my problem must be simple, but I still can't unlock it. I have seen some similar issues here, but because I am only a beginner, I am having problems implementing the suggested solutions, in my specific case which is the following:

[this is my UI, representing my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Ueq.png)

**My ImoClass:**
public class ImoClass {

```
private int imo;

public ImoClass(int imoj) {this.imo = imoj;}
   public int getImo() {return imo;}
```

**My RecyclerViewAdapater:**
public class ImoAdapterCLICK extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
public class MeuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public ImageView imagem, emoji;



    public MeuViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imagem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagem_item);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        emoji=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagem_select);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        //TODO: show image clicked in ImageView "emoji"
       // I have tested this: emoji.setImageResource(objetoClicked.getImo()) but without success !!



    }
}

private final ArrayList<ImoClass> meusItems;
public ImoAdapterCLICK(ArrayList<ImoClass> arrayList) {
    this.meusItems = arrayList;
}

@Override
public MeuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_grid, parent, false);
    MeuViewHolder viewHolder = new MeuViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MeuViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ImoClass objeto = meusItems.get(position);
    holder.imagem.setImageResource(objeto.getImo());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return meusItems.size();
}
```

}

**My "MainActivity":**
public class ImoRecyclerViewCLICK extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ImoAdapterCLICK adapter;
public ArrayList<ImoClass> meusItems;
private GridLayoutManager layoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_imo_grid);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 5);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    meusItems = new ArrayList<>();
    ImoClass item1 = new ImoClass(R.mipmap.imo1);
    ImoClass item2 = new ImoClass(R.mipmap.imo2);
    ...
    ImoClass item2 = new ImoClass(R.mipmap.imo30);

    meusItems.add(item1);
    meusItems.add(item2);
    ...
    meusItems.add(item30);

    adapter = new ImoAdapterCLICK(meusItems);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

I really appreciate any help. Thank you!! You've been a great help to me!!

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have a list of clickable images inside a RecyclerView. By clicking on an image I want it to appear in an ImageView. As shown in the image attached to the question. 

Note: I deleted code lines in onClik, which were my errors (Sorry!)So far onClick isn't doing anything. And I think this is where I should put the code that allows me to do the event of showing the image clicked.

Comment: Where is the imageView that you want the clicked image to appear in?

Comment: it is in the "R.layout.activity_imo_grid"  from " public class ImoRecyclerViewCLICK extends AppCompatActivity".
I'm actually calling it in   "public MeuViewHolder(View itemView) { emoji=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagem_select);
is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**According to how I understand the question, do this in `onBindViewHolder`:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MeuViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ImoClass objeto = meusItems.get(position);
    holder.imagem.setImageResource(objeto.getImo());

    //on click image
    holder.imagem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){

    //set the image clicked in emoji view

    holder.emoji.setImageResource(objeto.getImo());

    }

    });

}
```

**Remove this line from `MeuViewHolder`**

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: thank you so much for the effort, but it still stops app, when I click on an image (like before)

I'm trying to figure out how to access the error message (it seems to be something related to Logcat), to see what's really going wrong here. But like I said, I'm just a beginner... it's gonna be a "big walk."